# How does row operation work in the simplex algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-programming, gaussian-elimination

Reading through the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) for the simplex algorithm and I can't figure out how the row operation they have as an example works...

$$
\text{Minimize} \\
Z = -2x - 3y - 4z \\
\text{Subject To} \\
3x + 2y + z \le 10 \\
2x + 5y + 3z \le 15 \\
x, y, z \ge 0
$$

The next step makes the tableau that looks like this...

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
0 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 15
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So the top row is the function we are minimizing (set equal to 0), the other rows contain the constraints. And we have added one slack variable fo revery equation. They then select row 3 column 4 as the pivot and apply the row operation to achieve the following...

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2 & -11 & 0 & 0 & -4 & -60 \\
0 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & 15 \\
0 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 15 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I cannot see how this is the result of a row reduce operation. Not one of the numbers match up to what I would expect to see which would be the pivot row divided by the pivot value, and subtracted from the above row to make the pivot column in row 2 equal to 0. I would think that row 2 should look like this...

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{7}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second row is multiplied by 3, then the third row is subtracted from it. This is equally valid.

Comment: I feel so dumb for not seeing that now

Comment: I’ve definitely been there haha :)